# How can I convert this string into seperate numbers? I tried "parseInt" and "*"

Tags: javascript

I wrote a longer bit of code and this
is the part of it that doesn't work..

```
var inputs = "1234";
var outputs;
inputs = inputs.split("");
// this ->
for (var n = 0; n < inputs.length; ++n) {
    outputs += inputs[n];
    console.log(outputs);
}
```

It seems using this method the items are returned as strings. Okay, so lets convert them, right? I tried  "parseInt".

Did I do it right ?

```
parseInt(inputs[n])
```

Writing  this, I noticed that it might conflict with the "base" argument.

There is another reason to ask the Question, can I convert "1234" into an array that holds numbers?

Also I read somewhere I could use "*" and it would try to convert it, but I couldn't find where I read this.

Comment: YES! I have it  working now, 'for  (var n=0;n<inputs.length; ++n)       {
var digit = inputs[n];
digit = parseInt(digit);
outputs += digit;     console.log(outputs)
} '...  i  don't  like how it looks  though.

Answer (score 5):

You can use map and pass the value into the Number constructor:

```
inputs.split("").map(Number); // [1, 2, 3, 4]
```

Or call the prototype directly on inputs:

```
Array.prototype.map.call(inputs, Number); // [1, 2, 3, 4]
```

*Note:* This isn't actually *parsing* each number **and** it's worth noting that this will fail for any numbers greater than or equal to 10 in `inputs` because `.split` will only return single digits.

Answer (score 2):

You can use [`map()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map)

> The map() method creates a new array with the results of calling a provided function on every element in this array.

```js
var inputs = "1234";
//Split and convert to interger array
inputs = inputs.split("").map(function(i) {
  return parseInt(i, 10);
});

//Sum each element
var outputs = inputs.reduce(function(a, b){
    return a + b;
});
alert(outputs)
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
    var yourNumberString = "1234";
    var arr = Array.prototype.map.call(yourNumberString, function(current, index) {
      return parseInt(current);
    });
    console.log('Numbers Array', arr);
```

Answer (score 0):

This code might solve your problem

Open up your console and Click on run code snippet

```js
var inputs="1234";
    var outputs;
    inputs = inputs.split("");
    for(var n=0; n<inputs.length; n++)
    { 
      outputs = inputs[n];
      console.log(outputs);
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

You can convert the values to `int` and sum them using a map function. I also have added some validation when an non-numeric character is passed.

```js
var inputs = "1234";
var outputs = 0; //initialize
//Split and convert to interger array
inputs = inputs.split("").map(function(i) {
  intValue = parseInt(i, 10);
  if (!isNaN(intValue)) {
    outputs += intValue;
  }
  return outputs;
});
document.write(outputs);
```

Answer (score 0):

> can I convert "1234" into an array that holds intergers?

The answer is yes. you can do using `+` operator.
You can `.split()` to get an array of strings, then loop through to convert them to numbers, like this:

```
var inputs="1234";
myArray = inputs.split("");
for(var i=0; i<myArray.length; i++) {
    myArray[i] = +myArray[i]; 
}
console.log(myArray);
```

The +myArray[i] is just a quick way to do the number conversion, if you're sure they're integers
[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/efwom8h6/)

Answer (score 0):

More flexible and shortest version :)

```js
Array.prototype.sum = function() {
    for(var i=0, sum=0; i<this.length; sum+=parseFloat(this[i++]));
    return sum;
}

var inputs = "1234";

alert(inputs.split("").sum())
```